# Is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{1 + x + \dots + x^{n^2}}$ continuous on $x \in [0, +\infty)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity, uniform-convergence

Let
$$
u_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{1 + x + x^2 + \dots + x^{n^2}}, \\\\
f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n(x).
$$

I need to check whether $f(x)$ is continuous on $x \geq 0$

I came to:
$$
u_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
 1 \big/ (n^2 + 1), & x = 1; \\\\
 x^n (x-1) \big/ (x^{n^2 + 1} - 1), & x \in (-\infty, 1) \cup (1, +\infty).
\end{cases}
$$

I can show that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 1$:

$u_n(x)$ is continuous for all $n \geq 1$;

Weierstrass M-test: $\dfrac{1}{n^2 + 1} \leq \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n \geq 1$, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ is uniformly convergent $\implies \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2 + 1}$ is uniformly convergent;

There is a theorem: If $\sum g_n(x)=g(x)$ (uniformly on $D$) and each $g_n$ is continuous at a point $x_0$ of $D$, then $g(x)$ is also continuous at $x_0$.
Hence, $f(x)$ is continuous at $x = 1$.

Also, I can show that $f(x)$ is pointwise convergent on $x \geq 0$. But I don't know what to do with $x \neq 1$.

Comment: Can you add how you prove that $f$ is continous at $x=1$ ? It seems to me that it is easier to prove that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1[$ and $]1, +\infty]$...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, I added a prove

Comment: I see, but unfortunately, your proof makes no sense. What does it mean that "$\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ is uniformly convergent" ? You can only talk about uniform convergence for a series of *functions* (not a numerical series) on a given interval. The comparison test only proves here that $f$ is well-defined for $x=1$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Oh, I see. You are right. I meant to use a Weierstrass M-test

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure that Weierstrass M-test is easy to apply here on a interval that contains $1$ (whereas it is easy to apply on an interval that *does not* contain $1$).